# Line of sight roguelike

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas

So my algorithm for testing line of sight in a javascript canvas roguelike goes as follows:

- Set all tiles in a 1 dimensional array to black.
- Cast multiple for loops to check for solid tiles.
- If it is a solid run a tile setting function, then break loop. Otherwise set tile, and continue.
- In the tile setting function it will set the identified tile in the array to the specified tile, rendering the black, gone.
- A loop at the end draws all the tiles from the array.

Except now when I refresh the page, it just leaves a blank white screen, says the page is loading, it does not throw any exception nor errors, and I can't even log to the console to check where the code is breaking.

Any help would be appreciated, will post snippets of code if needed. I'm just perplexed by the fact that the styling and html of the page is all there, alas the code refuses to run.

Comment: Code is _always_ needed if we are to help you debug your code.

Comment: Sounds like possibly your code is not being loaded for some reason. Check the Network tab of the Chrome debugger (if you are using Chrome).

Comment: @NateFerrero will do

Comment: If its not throwing an error you will need to trace the code. In the javascript file add the line `debugger` where you call the function, this will stop execution at that point. Then open up dev tools and reload the page. Dev tools will stop execution and show you the current line (the debugger token) then use the trace controls (right top of inspection panel in source panel) and step over, or into the code. This will help you locate where your code is not doing as it should.